# Why the Callout option makes plotting performance poor

Tags: plotting, bugs, labeling, charts

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

The `Callout` option is a new option for plotting, but the performance is very poor, see bellow testing case.

```
num = 1000;
list = N@Sin@Range[num];
list2 = ReplacePart[list,num->Callout[Last@list,Last@list]];

GraphicsRow[{ListLinePlot@list // Timing, 
ListLinePlot@list2 // Timing}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

output shows as:
[image]

it spends more times running time when data plotting option `Callout` is used. I just wonder why?

Comment: I can reproduce this in 11.0. It seems fixed in V11.1.

Comment: Yes,I've checked, it does.